# Escaping ampersand in the regexp

Tags: java, regex

I have to match words which are ending with ampersand character. I came up with this regex: `\w*\&\b`. It works correctly for all letters, for example: `\w*a\b`, but when I add escaped ampersand (as in first example) it won't match words ending up with it.

Btw I was using https://regex101.com/ to test my regexps.

Comment: Ampersand is not a word character. So you want word characters, followed by an ampersand and then a word boundry which doesn't exist. Unless you have `hello&world`, I suppose.

Comment: @VLAZ OK so I guess `\w*\&$` would work. Thanks.

Comment: This was tagged Java so just remember that your regex would have to double up on back slashes \\&$

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 actually, no escapes are needed. `&` is not a special regex character, so no need to escape it.

Comment: @wdc - It will be easier for contributors to answer your question if you can update your question with some examples e.g. some valid and invalid strings.

Comment: Any luck with my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65703406/2191572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the same regex provided by @MonkeyZeus with a small correction to accept whole word *ending with multiple ampersands* (e.g. wordendingwithmultiple&&&&):

```
\w+\&+(?=\W|$)
```

`\\&+` instead of just `&`.

The demo [link](https://regex101.com/r/nuh3Tg/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
\w+&(?=\W|$)
```

- `\w+` - require at least one word char
- `&` - followed by an ampersand
- `(?=\W|$)` - positive lookahead after the ampersand for a non-word char or the end of the line

Just make sure to double up on the backslashes for Java string escaping:

```
\\w+&(?=\\W|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WaSEyJ/1/